# Can a user still see their video on their account if YouTube has removed it?

Tags: youtube

If I was to upload a video that contained nudity, for instance, and another user reported it and it was removed. Has it been removed from my account?

So if I did not have a copy of the video on my hard drive it would be gone for good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. The content is entirely removed from the platform and on that case, of nudity, your account is eligible for exclusion from the platform as well for the fact that such is considered a severe violation. 
Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802168?hl=en